# blazeds,how to know the client has "disconnected"?

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

The blazeds server-side don't know the client-side has disconnected. But it seems to know the client-side's network has down.

In my case, I use the polling channel, I download the blazeds's source code, and add some log output in the `FlexClientOutboundQueueProcessor.flush(MessageClient messageClient, List<Message> outboundQueue)` method.

Then I saw this, when a client subscibed, the server-side invoke the `FlexClientOutboundQueueProcessor.flush` method every 3 seconds, and print what I added in the flush method, then I only shut down the client's network, not close browser(client and server with difference network), I found the server-side don't print anything, it means that the server-side don't invoke the flush method.

And after more than 30 minutes I recover the client's network, the server-side continue to invoke the flush method (the client's session isn't destroyed, if I close the client's browser, after 30 minutes the server-side will destroy the session).

Now, I have two questions,:

1. How the server-side know the client's network has downed? Is there a listener to monitor the client's network? If so, where is it? If not, how and where the codes?
2. It seems that the server-side will invoke the `FlexClientOutboundQueueProcessor.flush` method every 3 seconds, can this interval be configured? And where the code to start or stop this timing task?

Answer (score 0):

Here answer on your first question: [Detecting (on the server side) when a Flex client disconnects from BlazeDS destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326927/detecting-on-the-server-side-when-a-flex-client-disconnects-from-blazeds-desti)

About configuration. You can configure in services-config.xml.

[Example BlazeDS applications](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=lcoverview_4.html)

[Configuring channels with servlet-based endpoints](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/lcconfig_3.html#1089380)

Comment: Hi!Thanks for answer,but maybe my bad expression,you have a little misunderstand.For my first question,I wasn't want to know how to detect when Flex clients disconnect,I want to know whether blazeds always detecting the client's newwork,so when i shut down the client's network,the server-side no longer invoke the flush method at once,if so,where the code?Then my second question,i have tried the properties in your offered link,but there's no effects,it still invoke the flush method every 3 seconds,can you directly tell me whice property to set the interval?Thanks!